# How to configure vue-router to ignore calls to one route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Let's say I have 3 apps `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` is the parent app which resides in the root directory of the server. `B` and `C` is under `/apps/B` and `/apps/C` respectively.

Navigating to `/apps/B` loads the correct app, but navigating to `/apps/B/xyz` redirects me to `/` which is the parent app `A`.

How do I configure `vue-router` to allow all calls to `/apps` to passthrough along with their corresponding query params?

Something like:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.fullPath.includes("/apps/")) {
    window.location.href = to.fullPath;
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the proper `publicPath` in your `vue.config.js` for the `B` and `C` applications - otherwise they will assume a deployment inside the root folder of the domain.

Comment: Yes, the `publicPath` property has been set right for the child apps. But that still doesn't impact the parent. So the calls to `/apps/B/xyz` will be handled by the parent first.

Comment: Then you can configure the VueRouter of the parent to use its catchall route `*` to reload the page with `window.location.reload()` (instead of showing something like "Route not found") and then the browser should supposedly fetch the child application from the server.